# Rails -- validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activemodel

I know that the `validates` method can validate presence, length, format, uniqueness, and confirmation.  However, sometimes I see people just setting these values to true/false, while other times they are more specific and pass in a hash that specifies the exact constraints (e.g. `:maximum => 50` for length or `case_sensitive => false` for uniqueness).  Is there a way that I can view a list of all the specifications that can be added to each of these validation tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right in the Rails API for ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods.

A list of validators and their respective options can be found here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html